# How to turn a sentence into a list containing its letters?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following string:

```
sentence = 'Python is a programming language'
```

How can I turn it into:

```
sentence_list = [P,y,t,h,o,n,i,s,a,p,r,o,g,r,a,m,m,i,n,g,l,a,n,g,u,a,g,e]
```

I wrote the following code but it doesn't give me what I want:

```
sentence = 'Python is a programming language'
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[i] == ' ':
        sentence_new = sentence.replace('sentence[i]', '')
sentence_spaced = ' '.join(sentence_new)
sentence_list = sentence_spaced.split(' ')
print sentence_list
#OUTPUT: ['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', '', '', 'i', 's', '', '', 'a', '', '', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g', '', '', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'g', 'e']
```

Comment: Strings in Python, as in many other languages, are iterable -- you can do `for` loops and such over them. In a very real sense, your sentence already _is_ a list of its component characters.

Comment: that should be the real answer. there's probably no need for this transformation.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Possibly, but it's better as a comment since the OP explicitly used list formatting in expected output and asked in a comment to another answer why the original code did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> sentence = 'Python is a programming language'
>>> 
>>> [c for c in sentence if not c.isspace()]
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'i', 's', 'a', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'g', 'e']
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) and [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (to remove spaces):

```
>>> sentence = 'Python is a programming language'
>>> list(sentence.replace(' ', ''))
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'i', 's', 'a', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'g', 'e']
>>>
```

If you want to remove *everything* that is not a letter, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
>>> sentence = 'ab1%^ &#$2cd'
>>> filter(str.isalpha, sentence)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you! I still would like to know why my code doesn't work if possible.

Comment: @user2357: because it doesn't make sense. the real question is why you though that would ever work.

Comment: @user2357 - Note too that `sentence.replace('sentence[i]', '')` is trying to replace the string `'sentence[i]'`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Or list comprehension with `replace`:

```
[s for s in sentence.replace(' ','')]
```